# Calculating Minimum Exam Score to Pass a Course

Tags: statistics

So for a course Im taking this semester 70% of the grade is based on the exam and 30% is based on project work. *In order to pass the course I need 40% combined score on the project and the exam.* I got 85% on the project.

How do I now go about calculating the minimum score I need on the exam to pass? Would it be simply calculating that I have $0.85*0.3 \approx 25$% score so far so I need to score $15$% or higher on the exam? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you score $e%$ in your exam. Then you need $$85\% \times 30\%+ e \% \times 70\%\ge 40\%  $$ or $$e\% \times 0.7 \ge 0.145 $$ or $$e\ge 20.714 $$ approximately. Good luck with your exam!

Answer (score 0):

Score in exam $ = S_e$

Score in project $ =  S_p$

To pass, total score $S = 0.7 S_e + 0.3S_p \geq 0.4$

$S_p = 0.85 \, (85\%)$. Now at equality, you find min $S_e$ from the above equation. Convert into percentage.

Answer (score 0):

> so I need to score 15% or higher on the exam? Or am I missing something?

Your answer is not "totally" to waste.

1. first you did not take 25% in the project score but you took $0.3\times0.85=25.5\%$
2. given the fact that you need more a minimum of $14.5\%$ you can easy calculate the minimum exam's score in the following way

$$\frac{0.145}{0.70}\approx 20.71\%$$

as showed by all other guys who answered